# What happens to suspended jobs in unix?

Tags: process, background-process, signals, process-management, jobs

We can issue <kbd>CTRL+Z</kbd> to suspend any jobs in Unix and then later on bring them back to life using `fg` or `bg`. I want to understand what happens to those jobs that are suspended like this ?  Are they killed/terminated ? In other words what is the difference between killing and suspending a process ?

Comment: wikipedia article should be a good place to start http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_(Unix)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The jobs are not killed, they are suspended. They remain exactly as they are at the time of the suspension: same memory mapping, same open file, same threads, … It's just that the process sits there doing nothing until it's resumed. It's like when you pause a movie. A suspended process behaves exactly like a process that the scheduler stubbornly refuses to give CPU time to, except that the process state is recorded as suspended rather than running.

Answer (score 8):

From a user's perspective, it means that the job is paused. It will no longer use any CPU. It *will*, however, keep using the same amount of RAM. That is why you can bring it back to the foreground with `fg` and it will **continue where it left off**.

If you kill a job and then restart it, it will start over from scratch.

Comment: Weill a "suspended" job be swapped out if there is not enough ram?

Comment: Hmm, good point, no idea. Ask @gilles, he might know.

Comment: Yes of course - as far as the OS is concerned, the pages allocated to a suspended or running job are the same.

Answer (score 1):

When suspend, the kernel doesn't include the process to the processor queue.
When killed, the stack (memory) of the process is released.